# Create dynamic environment variables at build time in Docker

Tags: docker

My specific use case is that I want to organize some data about the EC2 instance a container is running on and make i available as an environment variable.  I'd like to do this when the container is built.

I was hoping to be able to do something like `ENV VAR_NAME $(./script/that/gets/var)` in my Dockerfile, but unsurprisingly that does not work (you just get the string `$(./script...`).

I should mention that I know the `docker run --env...` will do this, but I specifically want it to be built into the container.

Am I missing something obvious?  Is this even possible?

Comment: When do you want `./script/that/gets/var` to run? Docker files are for build time.  If you want something to run at container boot time, just create a script that runs `./script/that/gets/var` and then the main command.

Comment: I want it to run at build time and create environment variables that will be present at run time.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

**Docker v1.9 or newer**

If you are using Docker v1.9 or newer, this is possible via support for build time arguments. Arguments are declared in the `Dockerfile` by [using the ARG statement](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/arg).

```
ARG REQUIRED_ARGUMENT
ARG OPTIONAL_ARGUMENT=default_value
```

When you later actually build your image using `docker build` you can pass arguments via the flag `--build-arg` as described in the [docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build).

```
$ docker build --build-arg REQUIRED_ARGUMENT=this-is-required .
```

Please note that it is **not** recommended to use build-time variables for passwords or secrets such as keys or credentials.

Furthermore, build-time variables may have [great impact on caching](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/impact-on-build-caching). Therefore the Dockerfile should be constructed with great care to be able to utilize caching as much as possible and therein speed up the building process.

*Edit: the "docker newer than v1.9"-part was added after input from [leedm777:s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27711304/create-dynamic-environment-variables-at-build-time-in-docker#answer-35025005).*

---

**Docker before v1.9**

If you are using a Docker-version before 1.9, the `ARG`/`--build-arg` approach was not possible. You couldn't resolve this kind of info during the build so you had to pass them as parameters to the `docker run` command.

Docker *images* are to be consistent over time whereas containers can be tweaked and considered as "throw away processes".

- More info about [ENV](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#env)
- A docker discussion about [dynamic builds](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/docker-dev/jbPMQb1Zefs)

The old solution to this problem was to use templating. This is not a neat solution but was one of very few viable options at the time. (Inspiration from [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/docker-user/Vi6oj9FW2m4)).

1. save all your dynamic data in a json or yaml file
2. create a docker file "template" where the dynamic can later be expanded
3. write a script that creates a Dockerfile from the config data using some templating library that you are familiar with

Comment: Re: "The purpose of docker images to be very consistent", I get that but this is specifically about the container, which has all kinds of dynamic stuff going on.

Comment: The problem with the template approach for my use case is that app is running on Elastic Beanstalk and the build step is controlled by the service so I can't get my template compiled in the place I actually care about it (though it would certainly solve this problem for other use cases).

Comment: @Evan hear hear, tough problem. Then the answer is: no - you are not missing anything obvious and it is not possible ;)

Comment: Well at least I can feel good about my research before posting this :)  Here, have a check mark.

Answer (score 33):

Docker 1.9 [has added support for build time arguments](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#190-2015-11-03).

In your `Dockerfile`, you [add an `ARG` statement](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg), which has a similar syntax to `ENV`.

```
ARG FOO_REQUIRED
ARG BAR_OPTIONAL=something
```

At build time, you can pass [pass a `--build-arg` argument](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#set-build-time-variables-build-arg) to set the argument for that build. Any `ARG` that was not given a default value in the `Dockerfile` must be specified.

```
$ docker build --build-arg FOO_REQUIRED=best-foo-ever .
```

Comment: Side question ... how is this passed to a build on elastic beanstalk? AFAIK you can't provide a build command to a docker deployment on Elastic Beanstalk.

Answer (score 4):

To build `ENV VAR_NAME $(./script/that/gets/var)` into the container, create a dynamic Dockerfile at build time:

```
$ docker build -t awesome -f Dockerfile .
$ # get VAR_NAME value: 
$ VAR_VALUE=`docker run --rm awesome \
    bash -c 'echo $(./script/that/gets/var)'`
$ # use dynamic Dockerfile:
$ {
     echo "FROM awesome"
     echo "ENV VAR_NAME $VAR_VALUE"
   } | docker build -t awesome -
```

https://github.com/42ua/docker-autobuild/blob/master/emscripten-sdk/README.md#build-docker-image