# Pass environment variables to Dockerfile during build time

Tags: docker

Is it possible to pass an environment variable to a dockerfile at build time, for instance, in order to install some files during the build that require authentication to fetch.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create dynamic environment variables at build time in Docker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27711304/create-dynamic-environment-variables-at-build-time-in-docker)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This method will achieve what you want, but is not recommended for secrets (secrets are hard).

You can use Build Args. The idea is that you place an `ARG` instruction in your Dockerfile which is then referenceable within the Dockerfile.

```
FROM alpine:3.3
ARG some-thing=<optional default value>
```

You can use this variable later in the Dockerfile like:

```
...
RUN echo $some-thing
...
```

Then when you build the image, you can pass the `ARG` into `docker build` like:

```
$ docker build --build-arg some-thing=some-value .
```

This will pass 'some-value' into the Docker build process as the `ARG` 'some-thing'.

You'd get

```
echo $some-thing
"some-value"
```

The values of your `ARG`s are *not* persisted in the end image though. So you don't have to worry about passwords etc leaking into the final image. However Docker still do not recommend it as a way of passing secrets.

Comment: The reason it's not recommended for secrets is the commands will end up in the Docker history.

Answer (score 0):

If you run `docker build --help` it will tell you what arguments it accepts. If you look through that you will find:

```
--build-arg=[]                  Set build-time variables
```

If you can't work out how to use it, consult the full Docker documentation.

Answer (score -1):

Dockerfile provides [Entrypoint](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/entrypoint) to achieve this. You can create a shell script as the entrypoint of your image, and this shell script could take some command as parameters.

[Here](https://github.com/feicun/image-builder) is an example that I created recently. The [entrypoint script](https://github.com/feicun/image-builder/blob/master/builder-entrypoint.sh) will take a SSH key pair as parameters, to clone a private git repository inside of the container.

Comment: But then all this stuff will be baked in the image? This is not the answer.

Comment: @JHarris Sorry I don't get your point. Could you let me know the meaning of "all this stuff"? Scripts or parameters or other things?

Comment: OK, so, you're not exactly doing that. I'm not really sure what you're doing. Your image builds another image by doing an intermediate clone. Why wouldn't I just clone on my machine then copy the code in before distributing it?

Comment: @JHarris Hi, my scripts is a part of another project, so it's hard to explain what I'm doing. I just use it as an example, to show that Dockerfile's Entrypoint could take parameters or environment variables.

Comment: Entrypoint runs in a container, not during the build process for an image.