# How to pass Environment variables as a parameter of a shell script in Dockerfile?

Tags: shell, docker, dockerfile

How to pass Environment variables as a parameter of a shell script in Dockerfile in runtime?

PUBLISH_HOST is taken from .env file

My docker-compose file looks like:

```
version: '2'
services:
tomcat:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        PUBLISH_HOST: ${PUBLISH_HOST}
        dockerfile: Dockerfile.tomcat
    container_name: tomcat
    image: tomcat-new:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

Dockerfile as below:

```
FROM 99taxis/tomcat7
ARG PUBLISH_HOST //taken from docker-compose  for all other this is working fine not working while passing in a shell script 
ENV PUBLISH_HOST $MAXPAAS_PUBLISH_HOST
COPY update-tomcat-path-config.sh /opt/tomcat/webapps
RUN cd /opt/tomcat/webapps && chmod 755 update-tomcat-path-config.sh && ./update-tomcat-path-config.sh ${PUBLISH_HOST}
```

But the input `${PUBLISH_HOST}` not accepted as a parameter in this shell script.

Is there any way to overcome this issue?

This is the Error Message I getting while trying `docker-compose up`

```
Step 25/37 : /opt/tomcat/webapps && chmod 755 update-tomcat-path-config.sh && /update-tomcat-path-config.sh ${PUBLISH_HOST} 
 ---> Running in 8ad3b1ecd73e

###################
Script starts Here:
###################

No parameter to the script is given, please enter it....!!!!
```

How to fix this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create dynamic environment variables at build time in Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27711304/create-dynamic-environment-variables-at-build-time-in-docker)

Comment: I think its not my issue is not able to pass a env variable as a argument in shell script inside dockerfile

Comment: "*it will not accept*" is not a problem description. What happens and what did you expect to happen instead? And what is `ENV PUBLISH_HOST $MAXPAAS_PUBLISH_HOST` supposed to do?

Answer (score 3):

See "[Setting Default Docker Environment Variables During Image Build](https://vsupalov.com/docker-build-time-env-values/)"

Your lines should be:

```
ARG PUBLISH_HOST //taken from docker-compose for all other this is working fine not working while passing in a shell script
ENV PUBLISH_HOST $PUBLISH_HOST
```

That would allow `ENV` to be overridden by `ARG` value at build time with:

```
docker build --build-arg PUBLISH_HOST=aValue
```

For [`docker-compose build`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/build/)

```
docker-compose build --build-arg PUBLISH_HOST=aValue aSERVICE
```

Note:

Your `docker-compose.yml` might not use your dockerfile, because `dockerfile: Dockerfile.tomcat` is not correctly indented.
See [`docker-compose.yml` "alternate Dockerfile"](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#dockerfile):

> Compose uses an alternate file to build with.
>   A build path must also be specified.

```
build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: Dockerfile-alternate
```

Comment: I need to pass a environment variable as a parameter for shell script but while trying to pass using the argument as follows ${PUBLISH_HOST} it is not working

Comment: sorry its auto edit. I am trying to pass argument as ${PUBLISH_HOST} its not accepting in shell

Comment: @AnishVarghese at build time? At run time?

Comment: docker-compose means run-time. ARG is for build time only. What "it will not accept means"? How are you passing a value using dokcer-compose? What are you typing? Please edit your question.

Comment: @AnishVarghese Don't comment: edit your question, please.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177144/discussion-between-anish-varghese-and-vonc).

Comment: @AnishVarghese Again, please edit your question (which you just did, and I reformatted it). See my edited answer. Also add in your question the exact docker-compose command you typed. Saying "While building the dockerfile using docker-compose" is not enough.

Comment: @AnishVarghese Thank you for the edited question (I reformatted it). See my edited answer.

Comment: Thank you somuch. Now I think everybody easily understands my problem

Comment: @AnishVarghese yes: the question is: did you build with `--build-arg PUBLISH_HOST=${PUBLISH_HOST}`?

Comment: I am just adding Dockerfile  named to build to docker-compose . All other environment variables  are working fine in all aspects, but while trying to pass  a parameter of the shell script  its not working and getting the above error

Comment: @AnishVarghese the indentation is important in a yaml file though. The docerfile is not an arg: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#dockerfile

Comment: got the answer. Thank you for your great support :-)

Answer (score 2):

I found out the answer.

To pass parameter in a shell script just use double quotes between the parameters

```
RUN cd /opt/tomcat/webapps && chmod 755 update-tomcat-path-config.sh && \
    ./update-tomcat-path-config.sh "${PUBLISH_HOST}"
#                                  ^               ^
```

Comment: Good catch. +1. Still not sure about your dockerfile argument though.