# Docker: set a return value as an environment variable

Tags: linux, bash, docker

I'm trying to create a temporary folder and then set the path as an environment variable for use in later Dockerfile instructions:

```
FROM alpine

RUN export TEMPLATES_DIR=$(mktemp -d)
ENV TEMPLATES_DIR=$TEMPLATES_DIR

RUN echo $TEMPLATES_DIR
```

Above is what I've tried, any idea how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything you run in a Dockerfile will be persisted forever in the resulting Docker image.  As a general statement, you don't need to use environment variables to specify filesystem paths, and there's not much point in creating "temporary" paths.  Just pick a path; it doesn't even need to be a "normal" Linux path since the container filesystem is isolated.

```
RUN mkdir /templates
```

It's common enough for programs to use environment variables for configuration (this is a key part of the ["12-factor"](https://12factor.net) design) and so you can set the environment variable to the fixed path too

```
ENV TEMPLATES_DIR=/templates
```

In the sequence you show, every `RUN` step creates a new container with a new shell, and so any environment variables you set in a `RUN` command get lost at the end of that step.  You can't set a persistent environment variable in quite the way you're describing; [Create dynamic environment variables at build time in Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27711304/create-dynamic-environment-variables-at-build-time-in-docker) discusses this further.

If it's actually a temporary directory, and you're intending to clean it up, there are two more possibilities.  One is to do all of the work you need inside a single `RUN` step that runs multiple commands.  The environment variable won't outlive that `RUN` step, but it will be accessible within it.

```
RUN export TEMPLATES_DIR=$(mktemp -d) \
 && echo "$TEMPLATES_DIR" \
 && rm -rf "$TEMPLATES_DIR"
```

A second is to use a [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) to do your "temporary" work in one image, but then copy the "permanent" parts of it out of that image into the final image you're actually shipping.

Comment: the actual reason why I want to use a directory  in /tmp is to avoid hassle with permissions. I want to use this dir for some assets which are generated during the installation

Comment: It's pretty common to run all the Dockerfile steps as root, which also avoids permission trouble.  Setting up an alternate user is a good idea, but I wouldn't actually switch to it until the very end of the Dockerfile.